# Every open set is a continuous image of closed set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to prove that every open set is a continuous image of a closed set, after failing to provide a counter example.
That is:

For every  $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$, there exists $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$  and $f:C\to U $ a continuous function such that $f(C)=U$.

I tried solving this with $n=m$ to get a rough idea for a more general case.
The best I could come up with was taking $C=U \cup \partial U$, closed set, and $f(x)=x$ if $x\in U$, however, I couldn't find a way to define $f:C \to U$ that is continuous.

I'd be glad for a hint in the right direction.

Comment: ... and you're never going to be able to find such a function, since the preimage of every open set is open for a continuous function.

Comment: I've spent hours of my life just because I wasn`t looking at the right definition of a continous function. Many thanks to you.

Comment: Making and realizing your mistakes is the best way to learn in my opinion!

Comment: @Sobi That's wrong, OP is not asking for a function on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the *preimage* of $U$ is closed, that would be impossible indeed. They are only asking for the *image* of the closed set to be $U$, and the function only have to be defined on this closed set. Of course, the preimage of $U$ will be an open *subset* of $C$, namely $C$ itself.

Comment: @klao Huh, you might be right. I may have been to quick to conclude here, I should probably get some sleep. My apologies to the OP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's known that every open set arises as a union of countably many closed balls:

$$U = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty B_k$$

Let $C$ also be a union of countably many closed balls, but make them disjoint:

$$C = \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty C_k \text{, where } C_k = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^m : \|x - (3k,0,\dots,0)\| \le 1\}$$

And let $f$ map $C_k$ to $B_k$ in an obvious way. Then $f$ is continuous and $f(C) = U$.

Comment: Thank you, That's a very helpful lead, I`ll try to generalize it for $n\neq m$ aswell !

Comment: @Sar You are welcome! For $n>m$ you just need a simple projection, but for $n<m$ you'll need something like Hilbert space-filling curve.